# create database on android

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have to create database with four table witch one ( nammed table_file) has foreign key from the other tables, first I try to create all tables at the same time but the table_file gives me errors related to  the foreign keys, so I comment the code that create this table in my DBhelper ,and I successfully create the other tables, but when I uncomment the tabe_file creating code abd try to create this table it say me : sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = no such table: file_table and i have that in the logcat

```
06-15 13:26:19.841: E/Database(24784): Error inserting file_category_column=0 file_theme_column=0 file_name_column=priv_priv_222_2012-06-15.pdf file_date_creating_column=1
06-15 13:26:19.841: E/Database(24784): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: file_table: , while compiling: INSERT INTO file_table(file_category_column, file_theme_column, file_name_column, file_date_creating_column) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?);
06-15 13:26:19.841: E/Database(24784):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method)
06-15 13:26:19.841: E/Database(24784):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.compile(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:92)
06-15 13:26:19.841: E/Database(24784):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.<init>(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:65)
06-15 13:26:19.841: E/Database(24784):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:83)
06-15 13:26:19.841: E/Database(24784):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:41)
06-15 13:26:19.841: E/Database(24784):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.compileStatement(SQLiteDatabase.java:1149)
06-15 13:26:19.841: E/Database(24784):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1569)
06-15 13:26:19.841: E/Database(24784):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1426)
```

how can I do to create this table?

Comment: YOu need to show us your code, not just the errors.

Comment: witch code you need my dbhelper class or the other class where I insert in tables

Comment: I ask whey it didn't add my file table, is it possible with sqlite on android add tables to  existing database at  any time we like?

Answer (score 0):

See this tutorial on SQLite.

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html

If it's complaining about no such table, then the table does not exist.  If you are upgrading your current schema, then make sure you are updating the database version, so the onUpgrade() get called, and make sure you are doing work in the onUpgrade()  so that the tables get recreated.

Comment: my problem is not how to create database, but how to create table with foreign keys when i try I have android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unknown column "file_category_column" in foreign key definition: create table if not exists file_table ( _id integer primary key autoincrement, file_name_column text not null,  FOREIGN KEY (file_category_column) REFERENCES category_table (_id),  FOREIGN KEY (file_theme_column) REFERENCES theme_table (_id),  FOREIGN KEY (file_date_creating_column) REFERENCES date_table (_id), file_cloud_column text default null,file_date_upload_column text default null);

Comment: fair enough, but your error message is clearly telling you that a table that you are referencing does not exist... so I can only assume that you are failing because the table is not there.  Once the table does exist, you may get another error, but until it is there, there no way you are going to be able to create a relationship to it.   Since your code for creating tables is not listed, the only things I have to go on, is how to ensure that you actually create a the required table.

Answer (score 0):

I have used a class to some function, you may try:

```
public PLSQLiteOpenHelper(Context context, String name, CursorFactory factory, int version, String tableNames[], String fieldNames[][], String fieldTypes[][]) {
    super(context, name, factory, version);
    TableNames = tableNames;
    FieldNames = fieldNames;
    FieldTypes = fieldTypes;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    if(TableNames == null){
        message = NO_CREATE_TABLES;
        return;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < TableNames.length; i++){
        String sql = "CREATE TABLE " + TableNames[i] + "(";
        for(int j = 0; j < FieldNames[i].length; j++)
            sql += FieldNames[i][j] + " " + FieldTypes[i][j] + ",";
        sql = sql.substring(0, sql.length() - 1);
        sql += ")";
        db.execSQL(sql);
    }
}
```

The above is only the create function. You may try to look at it.

Answer (score 0):

To add another table to an existing database, (assuming you created it within the app in the first place) you can change your `onUpgrade` method.

`onUpgrade` is called whenever the database needs to be upgraded.   It determines that by checking the version number you supply against the against the version number it stored the last time the DB was opened.  You must increment the VERSION_NUMBER in order for `onUpgrade` to be called.

```
@Override 
public void onUpgrade (SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) { 
    db.executeSQL(DATABASE_CREATETABLE2); 
}
```

DATABASE_CREATETABLE2 would be a string holding the sql statements to create your table (presumably just like you did for your other tables).